# Regex match only inner pattern?

Tags: java, regex

Hey I have the following string :

```
# The [[state]] that follows [[birth]], and precedes [[death]]; the state of
[[be]]ing [[alive]] and [[live|living]].#
```

Now what I wish to find is `[[live|living]]`, 
I've tried the following expression:

```
\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]
```

The problem is it matches the `[[` of `[[state]]`, the `|` of the right place and the end of the `]]`

How can I set a patter that will only get the most inner `[[` `]]` pattern? Maybe exclude in the `(.*?)` the closing square braces? if so, how can that be done?

**Note:** I'm using java so the `\` is actually twice, but simplified it with one `\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is it matches the `[[` of `[[state]]`, the `|` of the right place and the end of the `]]`

This is because you let your expression consume everything, as long as it's not a vertical bar.

If you change your expression to avoid closing brackets in the first group, it should capture the text that you want:

```
\[\[([^\]|]*?)\|([^]]*?)\]\]
```

Another positive aspect of this change is that it would eliminate [backtracking](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html) from the process of evaluation of your regular expression, which could significantly improve performance.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/KsTJpf)

Answer (score 0):

Use the negation character class of the square bracket `([^\[\]]*)` inside  your matches

```
~\[\[([^\[\]]*)\]\]~
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to match two consecutive brackets (`[[`) followed by **something** (`(.*?)`) and then a pipe (`|`) — that **something** is the problem because **it consumes too much**, although you've made the dot non-greedy..

Try this:

```
\[\[([^[]*)\|(.*?)\]\]
```

This pattern is more restrictive than the one using the `.`: The subpattern `[^[]+` matches a sequence of (consecutive) characters that are **not** the opening bracket.